# android : after drag textview by called layout(), setTextView() will revert TextView to Original Position

Tags: android

I custom a TextView to use Drag. TextView can Drag to the new position well. But when I change the Text Size by setTextSize(), the text will revert to old position before dragging. Because in setTextSize(), it call requestLayout().
How I fix this problem ?
thanks alot!

```
public class DTextView extends TextView{


    public DTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attribute) {
        this(context, attribute, 0);
    }

    public DTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attribute, int style) {
        super(context, attribute, style);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
            int bottom) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final int iAction = event.getAction();
        final int iCurrentx = (int)event.getX();
        final int iCurrenty = (int)event.getY();
        switch(iAction)
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mPreviousx = iCurrentx;
            mPreviousy = iCurrenty;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            dolayout = false;
            int iDeltx = iCurrentx - mPreviousx;
            int iDelty = iCurrenty - mPreviousy;
            final int iLeft = getLeft();
            final int iTop = getTop();
            if(iDeltx != 0 || iDelty != 0)
                layout(iLeft + iDeltx, 
                        iTop + iDelty, 
                        iLeft + iDeltx + getWidth(), 
                        iTop + iDelty + getHeight());

            mCurrentLayout[0] = iLeft + iDeltx ;
            mCurrentLayout[1] = iTop + iDelty ;
            mCurrentLayout[2] = iLeft + iDeltx + getWidth() ;
            mCurrentLayout[3] = iTop + iDelty + getHeight() ;

            mPreviousx = iCurrentx - iDeltx;
            mPreviousy = iCurrenty - iDelty;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely it will go to the original position because it's **always** there from its parent's view point. You only call `CustomView.layout` to layout the child but its parent doesn't know that. So you'll have to use another approach to fix this. Try calling [`View.setX/setY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX(float)) so that the `ViewParent` knows (and could handle) the translation.